# Google Apps script : Exceeded maximum execution time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

When copying a range of cells from one Google spreadsheet to another, if the number of rows is more than 20,000, an error appears: Exceeded maximum execution time.

```
function copySheetData2LTP() {  
  var sourceFolderId_2LTP = 'Id_from';  
  var sourceFileName = getCurrentYearAndMonth();
  var sourceSheetName = 'from';  

  var targetFolderId_2LTP_repeat = 'Id_to';
  var targetFileName = getCurrentYearAndMonth();  
  var targetSheetName = 'to';  

  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId_2LTP);  
  var sourceFileIterator = sourceFolder.getFilesByName(sourceFileName);  
  var sourceFileId = '';

  while (sourceFileIterator.hasNext()) {
    var sourceFile = sourceFileIterator.next();
    sourceFileId = sourceFile.getId();
    break;
  }

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceFileId);   
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);  

  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId_2LTP_repeat);
  var targetFileIterator = targetFolder.getFilesByName(targetFileName);
  var targetFileId = '';
  while (targetFileIterator.hasNext()) {
      var targetFile = targetFileIterator.next();
      targetFileId = targetFile.getId();
      break;
  }  
 var startRow = 1;
 var numColumns = 10; // Insert only first 10 columns before J        
 var batchSize = 50000; // Number of rows processed per operation
 var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceFileId);   
 var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);  
 var numRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow();

 var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetFileId);
 var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
 clearSheet(targetSheet);

 for (var startBatchRow = startRow; startBatchRow <= numRows; startBatchRow += batchSize) {
 var endBatchRow = Math.min(startBatchRow + batchSize - 1, numRows); 

 var rangeToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange(startBatchRow, 1, endBatchRow - startBatchRow + 1, numColumns);
 var sourceValues = rangeToCopy.getValues();

 var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(startBatchRow, 1, endBatchRow - startBatchRow + 1,         numColumns);
 targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
  }
}
```

The script execution time is 5 minutes, after which an error appears

Comment: I would take a look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Answer (score 0):

The easiest change to make your code faster is to avoid using `getValues` and `setValues` in your loops. This makes any GAS code very slow. Define the values you need to get in your loops, store them in an array and then use `getValues`, same thing for `setValues`.

Comment: Just boils down to storing all the rows so you want to copy into an array. Are you familiar with push?